Why does the sliding window algorithm not work for this problem statement?
The question is regarding an algorithm which I'm using to solve a problem. The problem statement is: (or view it here)
"Given arrival and departure times of all trains that reach a railway station. Find the minimum number of platforms required for the railway station so that no train is kept waiting.
Consider that all the trains arrive on the same day and leave on the same day. Arrival and departure time can never be the same for a train but we can have arrival time of one train equal to departure time of the other. At any given instance of time, same platform can not be used for both departure of a train and arrival of another train. In such cases, we need different platforms."
Example:
Input: n = 6, arr[] = {0900, 0940, 0950, 1100, 1500, 1800}, 
            dep[] = {0910, 1200, 1120, 1130, 1900, 2000}
Output: 3
Explanation: There are three trains during the time 0940 to 1200. So we need minimum 3 platforms.

I'm trying to use an algorithm as follows:
I'm creating an array consisting of each train's arrival and dept. time (so for the above test case, something like: [[0900,0910], [0904, 1200], ...] )
Then, I sort it based on the arrival times, and if two trains have the same arrival, they're sorted based on the departing times (ascending order for both).
I'm basically trying to find the maximum number of intervals that intersect. Consider the first interval: it has an arrival time of "a", departure time of "b". Now for any intervals that follow, if it's arrival is before "b", then I would require an extra platform for that train (since it intersects with the first interval). I keep doing this and finding more intervals, until I reach an interval that has an arrival time greater than "b". At this point, the first interval is no longer valid, since that train would've left, and so I increment my first pointer, and this process repeats. At any point of iteration, all the intervals between my "i" and "j" pointers will intersect. Finally, I return the maximum number of intervals that intersected as the answer.
This algorithm works for the initial few test cases, but for some reason it fails for certain other testcases.
The code below is what I've written for this algorithm. You can try to submit it on the above link to get the incorrect testcase (it's quite large, so I don't think I should paste it here. But if you want, I can paste the invalid testcase in the comments).
C++ Code
class Solution{
    public:
    //Function to find the minimum number of platforms required at the
    //railway station such that no train waits.
    static bool comp(pair<int,int>&p1, pair<int,int>&p2) {
        if (p1.first == p2.first) return p1.second < p2.second;
        return p1.first < p2.first;
    }
    int findPlatform(int arr[], int dep[], int n)
    {
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        int mxi = 0;
        vector<pair<int,int>>mp;
        for (int k = 0; k<n; k++) {
            mp.push_back({arr[k], dep[k]});
        }
        sort(mp.begin(), mp.end());
        
        
        while (j < n) {
            while (mp[j].first > mp[i].second) {
                i++;
            }
            mxi = max(mxi, j-i+1);
            j++;
            
        }
        return mxi;
    }
};

I'm not asking for the correct algorithm (as I've already read it and understood it). I just want to know why is this incorrect, and for what small test case would it fail, or if  I'm missing any other case.
PS. I'm not very sure of asking a specific problem on stack overflow, but I couldn't find any other relevant website/forum where I could get a quick, reliable answer.
Thanks!

Have you stepped through your code using a debugger yet?

Yes. I've run it through a debugger, and haven't observed an unexpected behaviour. Infact, the code passes the example test cases given, and a few others, but fails later. I'm not sure if it's the logic that's wrong, or I'm missing any other case in my code.

I've run it through a debugger, and haven't observed an unexpected behaviour -- That is not the job of the debugger to observe unexpected behavior.  It is your job to observe the unexpected behavior.  A debugger has no idea what your program is supposed to do, only you know this.  The debugger allows you to run your program a single step at a time, observe variables, see the program flow, and then you decide where and when the program takes a different path than expected.

Side note: Don't expect quick responses here. You gets what you gets.

Also, that site "geeks" is notorious for wrong information and incorrect C++ programming.  Finally, there is no need for a custom compare function for std::pair<int,int> when using std::sort.  The std::pair has an overloaded < that does the comparison.

Side note: Try to avoid i and j except where they match the variables given in the literature describing the algorithm. Some days it feels like I've paid most of my mortgage spotting where other programmers got their visually-similar variables crossed. You may not have crossed them here (or maybe you have and even I didn't spot it) but sooner or later you will.

If you are stuck finding a breaking input set, see if you can make one using fuzzing. Note that you cannot pick wholly random numbers because no train can have the same arrival and departure and presumably no train can depart before it arrives. One you find a breaking set, try to make it smaller. You'll learn a lot about the problem in the process, probably enough to be able to self-answer the question. But if not, adding the input set and a small main function that inputs it will make the problem look a lot more attractive to potential answerers.

Also know that the judge is going to be a complete bastard going out of its way to trip you up. When you come up with test inputs you need to be just as much of a bastard. Go out of your way to break the program. Be merciless.

Interesting note: 0000 ≤ arr[i] ≤ dep[i] ≤ 2359 and Arrival and departure time can never be the same for a train seem to be at odds. arr[i] ≤ dep[i] implies that arrival can equal departure.

Since it sounds like you have input where your program fails, what did you learn running the debugger with that input?

Using a debugger won't help you unless you can identify relevant test cases, expected output from those test cases, and (where failures occur) compare that with the output you get.    For the failing test cases, you'll need to determine - through analysis - what intermediate results are expected.   Then you'll be able to use the debugger (stepping through the code that implements the algorithm) to identify where behaviour of the code diverges from your expectations.

@PaulMcKenzie Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, but I meant that: I ran it through a debugger, but didn't observe anything that was failing the code for the testcase. The failing testcase had more than 800 arrival and departing times separately, so I could only analyse the starting few.

Often the debugger is of little help without a good-and-small input that causes failure.

It is incorrect to only consider the interval of a single train at a time. Consider the following 3 trains:
arrivals   = [  0, 100, 300]
departures = [500, 200, 400]

The time window during which the first train is at a platform fully covers the time window of the remaining two trains, but the second train leaves before the third train arrives, so its platform may be reused. Hence, only 2 platforms are needed in total, but your code outputs 3.
The correct solution is just a standard sorting of times and then keeping track of the current number of trains that are at a platform. Since the problem states that 0 <= arr[i] <= dep[i] <= 2359, this can actually be solved in linear time with a method similar to counting sort: just keep track of the number of trains that arrive and depart at each time.
int findPlatform(int arr[], int dep[], int n) {
    const int MAX_TIME = 2359;
    std::unordered_map<int, int> incomingTrains;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) ++incomingTrains[arr[i]], --incomingTrains[dep[i] + 1];
    int minStations = 0, currTrains = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= MAX_TIME; ++i)
        minStations = std::max(minStations, currTrains += incomingTrains[i]);
    return minStations;
}


For a slightly more difficult version of this problem, see Room Allocation from CSES. This one also requires outputting the room/platform assigned.

Thanks a lot. The test case that my algorithm was failing for, was outputting a larger answer than the expected answer. Probably because of many intervals like this.

@BlazeRod11 Happy to help.
